# I am facing 500 Internal server error: access denied to the file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a code for to print excel sheet using springboot.I am getting 500 server error saying access denied to the file

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadReport(@RequestParam(value = "employeeName", required = false) String employeeName,
        @RequestParam(value = "empId",required = false) Integer empId,@RequestParam(value = "skillMasters",required = false) Integer skillMasters,@RequestParam(value = "projects",required = false) List<String> projects,@RequestParam(value = "accounts",required = false) List<String> accounts, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, ParseException {
    CourseIndividualReportRequest courseIndividualReportRequest = new CourseIndividualReportRequest();
    courseIndividualReportRequest.setEmployeeName(employeeName);
    courseIndividualReportRequest.setEmpId(empId);
    courseIndividualReportRequest.setAccounts(accounts);
    courseIndividualReportRequest.setProjects(projects);
    courseIndividualReportRequest.setSkillMasters(skillMasters);

    service.generateIndividualReport(courseIndividualReportRequest);
    File file = new File("D:\\CandidateCheckedInReport.xls");
    HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    respHeaders.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "CandidateCheckedInReport");

    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
    if (file.exists()) {
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

service implementation

Comment: exception is like this java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\CandidateCheckedInReport.xls (Access is denied)

Comment: Have you double-checked the obvious? That is, you have spelt the filename correctly, it's in the root of the D:\ drive and the process running your application has permission to access it?

Comment: The user that the web service is running as does not have permissions to read this file.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely source of the problem is this:

```
InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
```

where the pathname for `file` is "D:\CandidateCheckedInReport.xls".

The most likely explanation is that the "user" that is running the web server does not have permission to read that file.   Web applications are often restricted from accessing files outside of the webapp or web container's tree.  This stops a hacker from exploiting security holes in a poorly written webapp to read and write arbitrary files in the server file system.

Solutions:

- Put the file you are trying to make available into the webapp or web container's file tree.
- Modify the access restriction to allow the web server user to access the file at its current location.  **Be very careful** to only allow access to those files / directories that *need to be* accessible via the webapp.

Comment: Thank you stephen for your answer. please let me know how possibilities to solve this issue

Comment: Please reread my Answer!   I can't be more specific because you have provided minimal information on the web container that you are using.